# Bamboo Wallboard order of plans

Tags: bamboo

We have a bamboo setup for our build environment(s) and every time we build something the bamboo wallboard gets updated with the result of the build (just like it is shown at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO40/Displaying+the+Wallboard). This is normal behavior. I would like to change the order of items in the bamboo wallboard so that the plan for the last built item is put to the first position on the wall. Is this possible?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but as it stands right now, there is no way to order the builds on wallboard by last built time.